# Shadowing Inherited Generic Interface Members in .NET: good, bad or ugly?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, shadowing

I know that shadowing members in class implementations can lead to situations where the "wrong" member can get called depending on how I have cast my instances, but with interfaces I don't see that this can be a problem and I find myself writing interfaces like this quite often:

```
public interface INode
{
    IEnumerable<INode> Children { get; }
}

public interface INode<N> : INode
    where N : INode<N>
{
    new IEnumerable<N> Children { get; }
}

public interface IAlpha : INode<IAlpha>
{ }

public interface IBeta : INode<IBeta>
{ }
```

I have places in my code that only know about `INode` so children should also be of type `INode`.

In other places I want to know about the specific types - in the implementation of my example `IAlpha` & `IBeta` interfaces I want the children to be typed the same as their parent.

So I implement a `NodeBase` class like so:

```
public abstract class NodeBase<N> : INode<N>
    where N : INode<N>
{
    protected readonly List<N> _children = new List<N>();

    public IEnumerable<N> Children
    {
        get { return _children.AsEnumerable(); }
    }

    IEnumerable<INode> INode.Children
    {
        get { return this.Children.Cast<INode>(); }
    }
}
```

No shadowing in the actual implementation, only in the interfaces.

Specific instances of `IAlpha` & `IBeta` look like this:

```
public class Alpha : NodeBase<Alpha>, IAlpha
{
    IEnumerable<IAlpha> INode<IAlpha>.Children
    {
        get { return this.Children.Cast<IAlpha>(); }
    }
}

public class Beta : NodeBase<Beta>, IBeta
{
    IEnumerable<IBeta> INode<IBeta>.Children
    {
        get { return this.Children.Cast<IBeta>(); }
    }
}
```

Again, no shadowing in the implementations.

I can now access these types like so:

```
var alpha = new Alpha();
var beta = new Beta();

var alphaAsIAlpha = alpha as IAlpha;
var betaAsIBeta = beta as IBeta;

var alphaAsINode = alpha as INode;
var betaAsINode = beta as INode;

var alphaAsINodeAlpha = alpha as INode<Alpha>;
var betaAsINodeBeta = beta as INode<Beta>;

var alphaAsINodeIAlpha = alpha as INode<IAlpha>;
var betaAsINodeIBeta = beta as INode<IBeta>;

var alphaAsNodeBaseAlpha = alpha as NodeBase<Alpha>;
var betaAsNodeBaseBeta = beta as NodeBase<Beta>;
```

Each of these variables now have the correct, strongly-type `Children` collection.

So, my questions are simple. Is the shadowing of interface members using this kind of pattern good, bad or ugly? And why?

Comment: Why not simply use a type argument to determine the type of a child. Then INode<IAlpha> would still have the same sematics but you wouldn't need to shadow at all

Comment: @Rune - What do you mean by a "type argument"?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I've edited my answer to simplify NodeBase's implementation of INode.Children - I've worked out what I was missing before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say you've got yourself a pretty complicated scenario there, and I generally *try* to keep things simpler than that - but if it works for you, I think it's okay to add more information like this. (It seems reasonable until you get to the `IAlpha` and `IBeta` bit; without those interfaces, `Alpha` and `Beta` don't need any implementation at all, and callers can just use `INode<IAlpha>` and `INode<IBeta>` instead.

In particular, note that `IEnumerable<T>` effectively does the same thing - not hiding one generic with another, admittedly, but hiding a non-generic with a generic.

Four other points:

- Your call to `AsEnumerable` in `NodeBase` is pointless; callers can still cast to `List<T>`. If you want to prevent that, you can do something like `Select(x => x)`. (In theory `Skip(0)` *might* work, but it *could* be optimized away; LINQ to Objects isn't terribly well documented in terms of which operators are guaranteed to hide the original implementation. `Select` is guaranteed not to. Realistically, `Take(int.MaxValue)` would work too.)
- As of C# 4, your two "leaf" classes can be simplified due to covariance:

  ```
  public class Alpha : NodeBase<Alpha>, IAlpha
  {
      IEnumerable<IAlpha> INode<IAlpha>.Children { get { return Children; } }
  }

  public class Beta : NodeBase<Beta>, IBeta
  {
      IEnumerable<IBeta> INode<IBeta>.Children { get { return Children; } }
  }
  ```
- As of C# 4, your `NodeBase` implementation of `INode.Children` can be simplified *if* you're willing to restrict `N` to be a reference type:

  ```
  public abstract class NodeBase<N> : INode<N>
      where N : class, INode<N> // Note the class constraint
  {
      ...

      IEnumerable<INode> INode.Children
      {
          get { return this.Children; }
      }
  }
  ```
- As of C# 4, you can declare `INode<N>` to be covariant in `N`:

  ```
  public interface INode<out N> : INode
  ```

Comment: Thanks for another excellent answer. The point about `AsEnumerable` being castable back to `List<T>` threw me. In Rx the `AsObservable` method **does** hide the source observable. I just assumed that `AsEnumerable` did so too. Maybe the Rx guys are just plain smart.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a type argument (that is an argument to the generic type) to determine the type of a child. Then INode would still have the same sematics but you wouldn't need to shadow at all
And you do indeed have shadowing in the implementation casting to INode will result in the same issues you describe in your post