# Interface inheritance limits

Tags: c#, oop, interface

Known that C# support interface inheretence, i want to create an interface "B" that inherits from a base interface "A" but also hides some interface "A" members, just like a Class uses explicit interface implementation to hide an interface member, unless the class instance is casted to the implemented interface:

***MyExample:***

First i create an interface `IDbObject` with some members and methods

```
public interface IDbObject
{
    IDbObject ParentObject
    {
        get;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

and then I create a second interface `IDbConstraint` that inherits the first interface but since inheritance is specialization I know more about the `ParentObject` member which i want to call `ParentTable` in the child interface.

```
public interface IDbConstraint : IDbObject
{
    // Hide IDbObject.ParentObject

    IDbTable ParentTable
    {
        get;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Why don't you just implement the derived interface IDbConstraint instead of IDbObject? Or depending what problem you're actually trying to solve, generics might be the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shadowing Inherited Generic Interface Members in .NET: good, bad or ugly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035781/shadowing-inherited-generic-interface-members-in-net-good-bad-or-ugly)

Comment: "Inherited" is always the wrong mental model when talking about interfaces.  You don't inherit squat from an interface, all you get it is a demand to write more code.  IDbConstraint has two members, nothing is getting "shadowed".  It gives you a headache when implementing it since their names are ambiguous, explicit implementation required to deal with it.  If you have the choice, you do, then just give them different names.

Comment: Declaring an interface IDbConstraint from scratch with half of the properties and the methods already declared in another interface IDbObject is just a waste of time and storage. Inheretence can solve this type of issues so why not use it ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the details and therefore I could say something wrong.
But i Think it could be a solution to use an abstract class instead of an interface.

```
public interface IDbObject
{
    IDbObject ParentObject
    {
        get;
    }
}
public abstract class IDbConstraint : IDbObject
{
    public IDbObject ParentTable 
    {
        get;
    }

    //Hidden becouse not public
    IDbObject IDbObject.ParentObject => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Using an abstract class instead of an interface is a major architectural change, in my opinion, it is considered a workaround more than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i know to this is to wait till the implementation time, then use explicit interface implementation to hide the ParentObject member, unless the instance is casted to IDObject:

```
public class DbConstraint : IDbDbConstraint
{
    IDbObject IDbObject.ParentObject
    {
        get;
    }

    IDbTable ParentTable
    {
        get;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```